# Bootstrap Jumbotron Background Image Not Setting in style.css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not able set the jumbotron background image from my external stylesheet file, although the styling works inline.

The stylesheet link can be found between the head tags and after the bootstrap link. I've been working on this a couple days with no success, can this be accomplished?

Here is what I have so far:

**CSS:**

```
.jumbotron {
    background: url('img/rocket.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color: #28b8f7;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #005D85;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #005D85;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!-- Jumbotron & Call to Action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-right"></h1>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
            <p class="pull-right"><br />
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-right jumbut" href="#signUpModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"></a></p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Although, this code seems to work as compared what I have already tried:

```
<!-- Jumbotron & Call to Action -->
<div class="jumbotron" style="background: url('img/rocket.png');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-color:#28b8f7;">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-right"></h1>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6">
            <p class="pull-right"><br />
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg pull-right jumbut" href="#signUpModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal"></a></p>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is the jumbotron file in a different directory than the style.css file? It seems like url being correct in one case and not in the other could be the root cause

Comment: Where is the css file in relation to the html file and more specifically to the image file? In your browser console you may be able to tell if there is a 404 when trying to load it or something. IF you moved to default bootstrap you may need to do '../img/rocket.png'

Comment: The html file is in the root folder, it's index.html.  The image file is in the img directory under root, style.css in the css folder under root.  The style.css is styling other elements, just not the jumbotron background.  The CSS in the style tag in the jumbotron element is the exact same as the one in the css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your last comment, it is simply a case of your url being wrong for the location you are currently in. From what I gather, this is your basic structure

```
-index.html
-css (folder)
--style.css
-img (folder)
--rocket.png
```

You have defined in your style.css the following property

```
background: url('img/rocket.png');
```

Since your css is in a folder called 'css' under root, when the browser looks at your url it will resolve it relative to its current location, so it will end up requesting `http://yourgreatsite.com/css/img/rocket.png`. This is why it worked when you put it directly in your html, since it was resolving the url relative to its currently location, which was the root, so it ended up requesting `http://yourgreatsite.com/img/rocket.png`.

It's very simple to solve, use dots to tell the browser to navigate 'up' out of your css folder and then into your image folder.

```
background: url('../img/rocket.png');
```

This would have been really obvious if you used your browsers built in developer tools. Most modern browsers have some Developer tools or 'Inspectors' available. Open one of these and you'll generally find a panel called 'Net' or 'Network' or 'Requests'. This will list every request your web page is making, internally or externally, and highlight any that have gone wrong. In this case it would have shown the request for your background image returning a '404 file not found' and showed you the url it was attempting to use. Learn to use the developer tools, they'll make your life a lot easier!